# Formato incorrecto en salida de lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente query:

```
 sqlLote = ("select lot.idLote from Lote lot \
 inner join [dbo].[Usuario] u on lot.idUsuario = u.idUsuario \
 where u.userName = '%s'") % \
         (usuario)
```

El resultado de este query por sql da

> 1 4 5 6 9

Cuando lo imprimo por pantalla los datos se ven de la siguiente manera:

```
cursorUsuario = connUsuario.execute(sqlLote)
print([x for x in cursorUsuario])
```

> [(1, ), (4, ), (5, ), (6, ), (9, )]

Porque no se muestra de la siguiente forma?

> [1,4,5,6,9]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres que se muestre de esa forma, deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
print([x[0] for x in cursorUsuario])
```